Manga/manhwa about a princess' life in a prison due to accusation that she killed someone
I read a manga/manhwa last month. I remember some details of the story. The princess is being accused of killing someone, so she is being locked up in an all-female prison, but it's not like a regular prison. It's a comfortable and a luxurious one. Her life in there is not safe, hence she is asked to be a prison wife to her roommate, because everyone there is afraid of her roommate. It turns out that her roommate is the male lead (ML).
For the ML, he has a long blonde hair, might be a witch or something. He asked for someone's help to change his and two of his friends' gender to become female to watch the female lead (FL) in the prison. His grandfather is a higher up witch, if I’m not mistaken.
The FL has someone that she is relying on to find the murderer, but he is suspicious. He is an orphan who has lived with her since his parents died when he was a kid. They aren't blood-related.

This is Prison Love.

Having never done anything bad and lived a dilligent life, Shushu is suddenly framed for murder and imprisoned in a prison for women.
In order to survive amongst harsh and vicious criminals.
“W-Will you be my prison wife?”
She becomes the wife of her very pretty but very scary roommate, who is also the prettiest(?) girl in the prison, Minicat.

The synopsis is a perfect match for the question.

The cover image includes the female protagonist and the male version of Minicat, with long white hair.

Is there, indeed, witches involved?
